# How to perform this complex integration?

Tags: matlab

Hi all I hope I can find help here. My question is regarding integral in MATLAB. Please don't be scared by the complicated notation. They are almost all constants.
I have the following function to integrate

```
syms v
syms gamma2
syms s
lambdav= (14679452516410005*exp(-(3*5^(1/2)*v^(1/4))/25))/(9223372036854775808*v^(1/2))    + (7339726258205003*exp(-(2*v^(1/4))/5))/(4611686018427387904*v^(1/2));
fun2=lambdav* (1./(1+s.*v^(-1)));
B=int(fun2,v,gamma2,+inf);
```

I would like the answer to be only in terms of gamma2 and s. The problem is MATLAB doesnt perform the integration and I get the following

int(((14679452516410005*exp(-(3*5^(1/2)*v^(1/4))/25))/(9223372036854775808*v^(1/2)) + (7339726258205003*exp(-(2*v^(1/4))/5))/(4611686018427387904*v^(1/2)))/(s/v + 1), v, gamma2, Inf)

which is basically the function I wrote.

Can anyone help me perform the integration?

Comment: Why not ask this in Math.SE and solve it by using mathematics?

Comment: The integration can't be solved in closed form that is why I tried MATLAB.

Comment: If you know that it can't be solved in closed form, then you probably shouldn't be using symbolic math. Why not solve this numerically? Also, your integration appears to be over the real domain. Are you using "complex" to mean complicated (though, I don't see anything complicated)?

Comment: I didnt mean by complex compicated. It just a warning for those who are afraid of ugly expressions.

Comment: How can I solve it numerically if the limit over which I am integrating is a symbol and not a constant i.e it is in this case gamma2

Comment: if for example I use integral instead of int, I get the following error: A and B must be floating point scalars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If int cannot compute a closed form of an integral, it returns an unresolved integral http://www.mathworks.nl/help/symbolic/int.html

Comment: Thanks, Do you know of any other function that can resolve it?

Comment: Do you know does the solution exist in a closed form?

Comment: You can set a grid of parameters and use of of numerical integration methods http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/numerical-integration-and-differentiation.html

Comment: Thanks, what do you set a grid of parameters, can I use numerical methods, note that I have $s$ symbolic while I am integrating over v

Comment: I don't think you can keep $s$ symbolic. By setting up a grid i mean you can set s = s0:ds:s1 etc. and perform numerical integration for every point (s,v,gamma2) in your parameter space

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to integrate analytically? Otherwise, use numerical integration:

```
q = integral(fun,xmin,xmax)
```

where fun is a handle to your function and xmin and xmax are the border values of your definite integral.